# Terraform Module with Count Can't Have Duplicate Elements

Tags: digital-ocean, terraform

Tricky one to explain in a title, or even form a question around it, so I'll start with some code (simplified for, err, simplicity):

```
resource "digitalocean_domain" "this_domain" {
  name       = "${var.domain}"
  ip_address = "${var.main_ip}"
}

resource "digitalocean_record" "this_a_record" {
  count  = "${length(var.a_records)}"

  domain = "${var.domain}"
  type   = "A"
  name   = "${element(keys(var.a_records), count.index)}"
  value  = "${lookup(var.a_records, element(keys(var.a_records), count.index))}"
}
```

Given the above being part of a module called `dns`, I can call it like this:

```
module "example_com_dns" {
  source = "./modules/dns"

  domain  = "example.com"
  main_ip = "1.2.3.4"

  a_records = {
    "@"    = "5.6.7.8"
    "self" = "9.10.11.12"
    "www"  = "5.6.7.8"
  }
}
```

Running this works as expected. I get the `A` records I expect; @, self, www, all pointing to the correct IPs.

However, it can't handle duplicate names. For example, putting in multiple `@` records results in only one of them being written, I'm guessing because each iteration for the name simply overwrites the previous `@` record.

Is there a way to have multiple duplicate names? i.e. In the example above, have something like:

```
    ....
    "@" = "5.6.7.8"
    "@" = "20.21.22.23"
    "@" = "30.31.32.33"
    "self" = "9.10.11.12"
    "www" = 5.6.7.8"
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case instead of using **keys** to get **map keys** you should put the A records into a **list** like:

```
a_records = [ 
  ["@" , "5.6.7.8"], 
  ["@" , "7.6.7.8"], 
  ["@" , "9.9.9.9"], 
  ["self", "7.10.11.12"], 
  ["self", "11.11.111.11"], 
  ["self", "12.12.12.12"], 
  ["self", "13.13.13.13"], 
  ["www" , "14.14.14.14"] 
]
```

and assign **name** and **value** as

```
name = "${element(var.a_records[count.index],0)}" 
value = "${element(var.a_records[count.index],1)}"
```

and you will get all the duplicate A records that you want

The following is a simple working example of how to do it.  You can cut and paste the code into a functional terraform session and it will run without errors and create duplicate A records.

You will need to extend the example to fit your needs of external modules, etc.

```
variable "a_records" { default = [
    ["@"   , "5.6.7.8"],
    ["@"   , "7.6.7.8"],
    ["@"   , "9.9.9.9"],
    ["self", "7.10.11.12"],
    ["self", "11.11.111.11"],
    ["self", "12.12.12.12"],
    ["self", "13.13.13.13"],
    ["www" , "14.14.14.14"],
    ["www" , "14.14.14.14"]
  ]
}

variable domain { default = "example20180731.com" }
variable main_ip { default = "1.1.1.1" }

resource "digitalocean_domain" "this_domain" {
  name       = "${var.domain}"
  ip_address = "${var.main_ip}"
}

resource "digitalocean_record" "this_a_record" {
  depends_on = ["digitalocean_domain.this_domain"]
  count  = "${length(var.a_records)}"

  domain = "${var.domain}"
  type   = "A"
  name   = "${element(var.a_records[count.index],0)}"
  value  = "${element(var.a_records[count.index],1)}"
}
```

This is another example.  It shows how to do it using external data supplied through a module.  It's also code which can be copied and pasted into a functional terraform session and will work, as is.

**create-dup-A-records.tf**

```
module "dns" {
  source = "./modules/dns"
}

variable domain { default = "example20180731.com" }
variable main_ip { default = "1.1.1.1" }

resource "digitalocean_domain" "this_domain" {
  name       = "${var.domain}"
  ip_address = "${var.main_ip}"
}

resource "digitalocean_record" "this_a_record" {
  depends_on = ["digitalocean_domain.this_domain"]
  count  = "${length(module.dns.a_records_in_dns_module)}"

  domain = "${var.domain}"
  type   = "A"
  name   = "${element(module.dns.a_records_in_dns_module[count.index],0)}"
  value  = "${element(module.dns.a_records_in_dns_module[count.index],1)}"
}
```

**./modules/dns/dns.tf**

```
variable "a_records" { default = [
    ["@"   , "5.6.7.8"],
    ["@"   , "7.6.7.8"],
    ["@"   , "9.9.9.9"],
    ["self", "7.10.11.12"],
    ["self", "11.11.111.11"],
    ["self", "12.12.12.12"],
    ["self", "13.13.13.13"],
    ["www" , "14.14.14.14"],
    ["www" , "14.14.14.14"]
 ]
}

output "a_records_in_dns_module" {
    value = "${var.a_records}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer :)

Putting aside for the moment the argument that @ A records need to be unique or not (I don't think they do: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035), I'm asking specifically how to achieve this in Terraform. Doing the same thing outside of a loop works perfectly (multiple "@" A records are created).

Comment: In that case instead of using **keys** to get map keys you should put the A records into a list like:
`code`
  a_records = [
    ["@"   , "5.6.7.8"],
    ["@"   , "7.6.7.8"],
    ["@"   , "9.9.9.9"],
    ["self", "7.10.11.12"],
    ["self", "11.11.111.11"],
    ["self", "12.12.12.12"],
    ["self", "13.13.13.13"],
    ["www" , "14.14.14.14"]
   ]
`code`
and assign “name” and “value “ as
 `code`
  name   = "${element(var.a_records[count.index],0)}"
  value  = "${element(var.a_records[count.index],1)}"
`code`
and you will get all the duplicate A records that you want.

Comment: @Don You should update your answer accordingly as this seems to be the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, element() has this limitation: "This function only works on flat lists" -- from https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#element-list-index-

And indeed I get "element: argument 1 should be type list, got type string"

Comment: In the code above **element()** does get a list as required and produces duplicate A records without any errors.  Can you post the code that you are using?  It sounds like you have the syntax wrong on setting up the list.  I'll also update the answer with a simple working example that hopefully you can extend to fit your situation.

Comment: Odd. It does indeed work fine if it's all in one file, but if you pass in the variables from outside, you get that error. i.e. If you call the module from a `main.yml` and pass in `a_records`, it fails, but if you put those same variables _inside_ the module (or even as the `default` value for the module's definition of them), it works.

Comment: It sounds like you are either not defining the data structure correctly in the child module or not referencing it correctly in the parent module.  I added an additional example of how to do it by passing data in from the outside using a module.

Comment: Got it, it's a (current) limitation of Terraform: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/18573#event-1765829698

It'll be addressed in 0.12, but for now you have to do the `split` hack described in the linked issue, which is icky.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a limitation of Terraform:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/18573#event-1765829698

@don is mostly there in his answer, but you can't have that work with passed in variables. You need to use the `split` hack to pass it is as a string, then make it a list, as described in the above linked issue:

Call from main.tf:

```
module "example_com_dns" {
  source = "./modules/dns"

  domain  = "example.com"
  main_ip = "${lookup(var.example_com_dns, "at01")}"

  a_records = [
    "@ 5.6.7.8",
    "@ 7.6.7.8",
  ]
}
```

dns.tf module:

```
resource "digitalocean_record" "this_a_record" {
  depends_on = ["digitalocean_domain.this_domain"]
  count  = "${length(var.a_records)}"

  domain = "${var.domain}"
  type   = "A"
  name   = "${element(split(" ", var.a_records[count.index]),0)}"
  value  = "${element(split(" ", var.a_records[count.index]),1)}"
}
```

For whoever else is trying to do this from a Google search; my advice is don't. 0.12 will be out soon, and will fix all these kinds of insanity.